# How to stop original array object from moving (circular array)

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to get this rectangular object to array in a circle, evenly spaced so I can execute a boolean. I am able to do this, however for some reason, every time I do the original array object for the modifier moves one place over (I'm guessing 4.5°) away from the Y axis which I want it to keep locked on. This is because it is then much easier to edit down the line. How do i keep it locked to the Y axis and not move at all?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello it's hard to understand could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Array modifier shouldn't move the original object  Maybe you parented the original object to the used empty? Select the original object and alt+P, clear parent.

Comment: Shared the file here [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=zy9PlY0d" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/zy9PlY0d/)

Comment: I tried to clear parent, still did the same thing when I tried the array :(

Answer (score 1):

Your array modifier doesn't rotate your object, which you can clearly see by disabling/removing it:

[image]

You rotated the object yourself. So it is rotated. In order to apply object offset, don't rotate original object, rotate the empty used as object offset:

[image]